# What do "signals:" and "private slots:" mean in the following code?

Tags: c++, qt

In [this link](https://wiki.qt.io/Download_Data_from_URL) there is the following code:

```
class FileDownloader : public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT
 public:
  explicit FileDownloader(QUrl imageUrl, QObject *parent = 0);
  virtual ~FileDownloader();
  QByteArray downloadedData() const;

 signals:
  void downloaded();

 private slots:
  void fileDownloaded(QNetworkReply* pReply);
  private:
  QNetworkAccessManager m_WebCtrl;
  QByteArray m_DownloadedData;
};
```

What do the colons in `signals:` and `private slots:` mean? Code generally uses this symbol for labels but these don't seem like labels.

Comment: It's a [Qt](https://www.qt.io/product/framework) specific thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks but how this is a valid c++ code?

Comment: Qt uses a preprocessor to connect *signals* and *slots* for asynchronous event handling. The preprocessor then generates the actual code without these parts for the compiler itself. So it's true that it's not proper C++, but the C++ compiler will never see these parts (if you build your code correctly).

Comment: It is Qt equivalence of representing an events. Privates Signals means event only related within class, without specifier signals is public event for GUI applications

Comment: Read the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html

Comment: The [Qt for Beginners](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners#Important_macros) page mentions that these are macros, suggesting that what the compiler sees will be different than what you see.

Comment: Related (but old -- some details might be out of date): [What exactly are signals and slots in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985492/what-exactly-are-signals-and-slots-in-qt)